# I replaced my faucet supply line but it's still leaking. Any ideas?

Tags: leak, faucet

[image]

My cold water supply line (braided steel) on my kitchen sink seemed to be leaking at the (1/2") connection.  I replaced the line with a similar braided unit. I tightened it hand tight, then a half turn with wrench. It was till leaking so I tightened it more. I also tried removing and reattaching  it (extra snug) and it's still leaking.

I'm really baffled on this one. **I noticed the male threads are not completely in the round (they have flat sides)**, but there is nothing unique about the supply line that was removed.  No sign of teflon tape, and I didn't use any.

In the picture, you'll note the new line (cold supply) is on the left with a drip at the connection. The hot water line is in the middle (you can see flat sides) and the wand lines are also visible.

---

Also, can someone please advise as to how to disconnect the black plastic connection that connects the wand to the faucet (in foreground on right in picture)?  Thanks!

Comment: If you remove the braided line and feel the flared brass part, do you feel any cracks or misshapen sections?

Comment: There is normally no reason to use sealing tape or dope on this kind of connection because those are designed to make *threads* water tight. With this kind of supply hose the threads are not exposed to water; the threads provide the force which presses the sealing surfaces together.

Answer (score 1):

These fittings seal by a soft elastomer seal in the hose fitting to a smooth mating surface on the faucet fitting. I would just keep tightening until the leak stops.

If you cannot get it to stop by tightening, you could cut off the fitting on the faucet  and put on a new fitting (compression or sweat on). Is the mating surface damaged? Are the threads on the faucet fitting damaged (e.g., from prior cross threading) so that the mating surface is not being pressed square onto the seal?

If you can see or feel a groove in the sealing surface of the faucet fitting, you could try to restore the surface by filing or sanding. If it is a deep crack, then you could try to fill it with super glue or other sealer, but probably this wouldn't work.

You could get an adapter which you could thread onto the existing faucet fitting (with pipe dope or tape) and which would have undamaged threads and sealing surface and to which the supply hose would make a leak free seal. This might require two pieces--a "nipple" and an adapter which screws into or onto the nipple and has the correct male ending for the supply hose to attach to. The pipe thread connections on each end of the nipple would require sealing with pipe dope or tape, but not the final connection of the supply hose.

**EDIT**

> I'm really baffled on this one. I noticed the male >threads are not completely in the round (they have flat >sides), but there is nothing unique about the supply line >that was removed. No sign of Teflon tape, and I didn't >use any.

AFIK the presence of flat sides means that these threads could never seal and are only "clamping" threads so my statement above about putting on an adapter w or w/o a nipple wouldn't work. Only round threads can seal.

Answer (score 0):

- Do you have a washer inside the supply line?
- If so, replace the washer. It could be bad.
- Check the male pipe to make sure the connecting surface isn't damaged/calcified.
- You shouldn't have to use teflon tape.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The hot water line that extends down from the faucet itself, that particular pipe which came with the faucet from the factory was the culprit. It screws into the bottom of the faucet and it was leaking. Might be the same in your case. I am in no way shape or form a plumber tho.